# Schottky Diodes Depletion Region

Tags: schottky

When there is diffusion of electrons to the metal from the n-type semiconductor, why does Wikipedia says there is no charge carrier depletion region at the junction in a Schottky Diode?

Comment: Metals have... "flexible" orbital structures.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is a depletion region at Schottky Diode metal-semiconductor-junctions. Wikipedia also isn´t consistent about this - the first state there is a depletion zone and later neglect it. The german article however also states there is a depletion zone.

The recovery time of Schottky Diodes is shorter than for other diodes because of a different reason:
Schottky Diodes are unipolar elements, only electrons contribute to the current. There is no need for recombination at the depletion zone, so recovery is a lot faster.